# SwiftUI .onAppear, only running once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, onappear

In a `SwiftUI` app I have code like this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        ........
    }
    .onAppear {
      .... I want to have some code here ....
      .... to run when the view appears ....
    }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to run some code inside the *.onAppear* block, so that it gets run when the app appears on screen, after launching or after being in the background for a while. But it seems like this code is only run once at app launch, and never after. Am I missing something? Or should I use a different strategy to get the result I want?

Comment: it will get called everytime view appear

Comment: That is what I would like, but when I try it does not work like that. As explained in my post.

Comment: strange for me ... ca you share demo project to see ?

Comment: @jawadAli, start an app (using code similar to my post), then tap the home button, then tap the icon of the app to bring it back. You will see that the .onAppear code block is executed only once. The same is true if you come back to the app tapping on a universal link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would have to observe the event when the app is entering foreground and publish it using `@Published` to the `ContentView`. Here's how:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observer = Observer()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            //...
        }
        .onReceive(self.observer.$enteredForeground) { _ in
            print("App entered foreground!") // do stuff here
        }
    }
}

class Observer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var enteredForeground = true

    init() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        } else {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func willEnterForeground() {
        enteredForeground.toggle()
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to spend a bit more time digging, but with the few tests I made, it already  seems like this approach can lead to something. Using the method: func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {}.

Comment: Yes, the above is just a glimpse of what can be achieved. You can modify it however you wish to obtain the results you like :)

Comment: Yes, I am still beginning with SwiftUI. There seem to be a lot left that I don't quite understand at this point or may be don't even know about. ObservedObject, EnvironmentObject ... are among those.

Comment: SwiftUI has introduced a lot of great things to us. But, there isn't anything to worry about. You'll find these making more sense as you use them more frequently :)

Comment: do we need to remove the observer in the deinit ?

Comment: @Hatim Sure bro. You can use a simple `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` in your `deinit` method.

Answer (score 28):

If you're linking against iOS14 then you can take advantage of the new `scenePhase` concept:

```swift
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
```

Where ever you are the Environment if injecting this property that you can test against three conditions:

```swift
switch newPhase {
    case .inactive:
        print("inactive")
    case .active:
        print("active")
    case .background:
        print("background")
}
```

So, all together:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                switch newPhase {
                    case .inactive:
                        print("inactive")
                    case .active:
                        print("active")
                    case .background:
                        print("background")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.onFirstAppear` modifier like:

```
Text("Hello World")
    .onFirstAppear {
        /* The code here only runs on the first appear */
    }
```

You just need to implement a simple extension:

```
public extension View {
    func onFirstAppear(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(ViewFirstAppearModifier(perform: action))
    }
}

struct ViewFirstAppearModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var didAppearBefore = false
    private let action: () -> Void

    init(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            guard !didAppearBefore else { return }
            didAppearBefore = true
            action()
        }
    }
}
```